# How to use materialized view on wildcard tables?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, materialized-views

I am getting error :

> Materialized view query cannot reference wildcard tables.

I have  tried creating a materialized view on table whose address is like
`bigquery-public-data.ga4_obfuscated_sample_ecommerce.events_*`

What can i do??

Comment: Materialized views have many restriction and limits because Google CLoud performs incremental update of the views: faster and cheaper for everyone. But, since a days, there is a new feature: Non incremental materialized views. It goes beyond the current limits but will cost more because the update is full (and non incremental). It's the best option if economically suitable:https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/materialized-views-create#non-incremental